# Hive - find the updates done by the user

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am looking for a way to find out who ran update/drop/alter commands on Hive external table. I am not interested in select, show commands.

I couldn't find any way to figure it out. Is there any way to find it out?

If we need to do any prior work, fine as well.

Any suggestions?

Comment: are the hive logs activated and being stored?

Comment: @hlagos Yes. Hive meta server logs are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I found a script in python that extracts all the SQL commands with user, you could extend that script.

```
./hqe.py --help 
usage: hqe.py [-h] [--since SINCE] [--to TO] [--logdir LOGDIR]
          [--glob LOGFILE_GLOB]
          [--loglevel {DEBUG,INFO,WARNING,ERROR,CRITICAL}]

Displays queries ran on Hive.

optional arguments:
 -h, --help show this help message and exit
 --since SINCE how far to look back. (default: 15m)
 --to TO How far to look forward. (default: now)
 --logdir LOGDIR Directory of hive log files. (default: /var/log/hive)
 --glob LOGFILE_GLOB Shell pattern of hive logfiles inside their logdir.
 (default: hiveserver2.log*)
 --loglevel {DEBUG,INFO,WARNING,ERROR,CRITICAL}, -l {DEBUG,INFO,WARNING,ERROR,CRITICAL}
 Log level. (default: warn)
```

If user, hostname and duration are know they are displayed,
query is displayed with the same formatting as it was sent, inclusive comments,

The Blog post: https://thisdataguy.com/2017/06/23/extracting-queries-from-hive-logs/

[Github Project](https://github.com/lomignet/thisdataguy_snippets/tree/master/hive_queries_extractor)